# Perform similar computations in every dataframe in a list of dataframes

Tags: pandas, for-loop, functional-programming

I have a list of 18 different dataframes. The only thing these dataframes have in common is that each contains a variable that ends with "_spec". The computations I would like to perform on each dataframe in the list are as follows:

1. return the number of columns in each dataframe that are numeric;
2. filter the dataframe to include only the "_spec" column if the sum of the numeric columns is equal to #1 (above); and
3. store the results of #2 in a separate list of 18 dataframes

I can get the output that I would like for each individual dataframe with the following:

```
lvmo_numlength = -len(df.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist()) # count (negative) no. of numeric vars in df
lvmo_spec = df[df.sum(numeric_only=True,axis=1)==lvmo_numlength].filter(regex='_spec') # does ^ = sum of numeric vars?
lvmo_spec.to_list()
```

but I don't want to copy and paste this 18(+) times...

I am new to writing functions and loops, but I know these can be utilized to perform the procedure I desire; yet I don't know how to execute it. The below code shows the abomination I have created, which can't even make it off the ground. Any suggestions?

```
# make list of dataframes
name_list = [lvmo, trx_nonrx, pd, odose_drg, fx, cpn_use, dem_hcc, dem_ori, drg_man, drg_cou, nlx_gvn, nlx_ob, opd_rsn, opd_od, psy_yn, sti_prep_tkn, tx_why, tx_curtx]

# create variable that satisfies condition 1
def numlen(name):
    return name + "_numlen"

# create variable that satisfies condition 2
def spec(name):
    return name + "_spec"    

# loop it all together
for name in name_list:
    numlen(name) = -len(name.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist())
    spec(name) = name[name.sum(numeric_only=True,axis=1)]==numlen(name).filter(regex='spec')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what I believe your question is asking as follows, given input `df_list` which is a list of dataframes:

```py
res_list = [df[df.sum(numeric_only=True,axis=1) == -len(df.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist())].filter(regex='_spec') for df in df_list]
```

Explanation:

- for each input dataframe, create a new dataframe as follows: for rows where the sum of the values in numeric columns is <=0 and is equal in magnitude to the number of numeric columns, select only those columns with a label ending in '_spec'
- use a list comprehension to compile the above new dataframes into a list

Note that this can also be expressed using a standard for loop instead of a list comprehension as follows:

```py
res_list = []
for df in df_list:
    res_list.append( df[df.sum(numeric_only=True,axis=1) == -len(df.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist())].filter(regex='_spec') )
```

---

Sample code (using 7 input dataframe objects instead of 18:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_list = [pd.DataFrame({'b':['a','b','c','d']} | {f'col{i+1}{"_spec" if not i%3 else ""}':[-1,0,0]+([0 if i!=n-1 else -n]) for i in range(n)}) for n in range(7)]
for df in df_list: print(df)

res_list = [df[df.sum(numeric_only=True,axis=1) == -len(df.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist())].filter(regex='_spec') for df in df_list]
for df in res_list: print(df)
```

Input:

```
   b
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
   b  col1_spec
0  a         -1
1  b          0
2  c          0
3  d         -1
   b  col1_spec  col2
0  a         -1    -1
1  b          0     0
2  c          0     0
3  d          0    -2
   b  col1_spec  col2  col3
0  a         -1    -1    -1
1  b          0     0     0
2  c          0     0     0
3  d          0     0    -3
   b  col1_spec  col2  col3  col4_spec
0  a         -1    -1    -1         -1
1  b          0     0     0          0
2  c          0     0     0          0
3  d          0     0     0         -4
   b  col1_spec  col2  col3  col4_spec  col5
0  a         -1    -1    -1         -1    -1
1  b          0     0     0          0     0
2  c          0     0     0          0     0
3  d          0     0     0          0    -5
   b  col1_spec  col2  col3  col4_spec  col5  col6
0  a         -1    -1    -1         -1    -1    -1
1  b          0     0     0          0     0     0
2  c          0     0     0          0     0     0
3  d          0     0     0          0     0    -6
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3]
   col1_spec
0         -1
3         -1
   col1_spec
0         -1
3          0
   col1_spec
0         -1
3          0
   col1_spec  col4_spec
0         -1         -1
3          0         -4
   col1_spec  col4_spec
0         -1         -1
3          0          0
   col1_spec  col4_spec
0         -1         -1
3          0          0
```

---

Also, a couple of comments about the original question:

- `lvmo_spec.to_list()` doesn't work because `to_list()` is not defined. There is a method named `tolist()`, but it will only work for a Series (not a DataFrame).
- `lvmo_numlength = -len(df.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist())` gives a negative result. I have assumed this is your intention, and that you want the sum of each row's numeric values to have a negative value, but this is slightly at odds with your description which states:

  ```
  return the number of columns in each dataframe that are numeric;
  filter the dataframe to include only the "_spec" column if the sum of the numeric columns is equal to #1 (above);
  ```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks! Double thanks for the comments; the appropriate edit was made to the inline comment.